# Did people at the time think that the founding fathers were religious men?

Tags: united-states, religion, christianity, everyday-life, founding-fathers

People today think for some reason that the founding fathers were religious men, you know "Good-old Christians" and the sort.

Of course this isn't exactly true. Sure, they did think a god of some sort existed, but if they said things like "It's made one half the world fools and the other half hypocrites", and "Lighthouses are more useful then churches", then it's safe to assume that they were for the most part deists, merely using a god to "Fill in the gaps" if you will.

That said, they were also part of the upper class, a position that often buys you a chance to doubt your faith in a way the more desperate lower class folk often couldn't or didn't want to. Thus, it's safe to assume most people were more religious at the time.

But I'm curious, what exactly did the poorer majority think of their dear founding fathers religious stance(s)? Did they know of their doubts and if so did they think less of them for that? Or is it like today, where most people wrongly assume the founding fathers to be faithful men of the book, oblivious to their actual alignment?

Comment: WRT your last paragraph, perhaps it would be helpful to ask what percentage of the general population of the time was more than nominally religious.

Comment: Please, provide sources of your quotes as well as names. Also, how many of the founding fathers are you asking about? Everybody who signed DoI? "They" were definitely not homogeneous in their beliefs.

Comment: I think there's strong evidence that some of the big names like Jefferson were probably not Christians but kept their personal convictions closely guarded. [Consider the purpose and history of the Jefferson Bible](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/41564/are-there-any-active-christian-ministries-that-preach-from-the-jefferson-bible/41565#41565). Even today, an open atheist will likely not win any American election, so it's really not a stretch to think the average revolutionary American believed the founding fathers were true believers.

Comment: [An interesting list of religious quotes from some founding fathers](https://wallbuilders.com/founding-fathers-jesus-christianity-bible/). I found Jefferson's and Franklin's interesting. Most in the list are not well known anymore, if they ever were.

Comment: @fredsbend - A [large amount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deists) of the "Founders", including 3 of the first 4 presidents were what we call [Deists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deism). They believed in God, but not the Trinity. Most Christians today would not consider a Deist a Christian.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, but did they let on publicly that they denied Christ's divinity? That's the question. I doubt it.

Comment: The Founding Fathers were Deists-(perhaps with the exception of George Washington, was a Mason).  Benjamin Franklin, for example, edited the most famous line in "The Declaration of Independence", "We hold these truths to be self-evident that all men are created equal and are endowed by their Creator......."; it was actually Franklin who inserted the word, "self-evident". whereas Thomas Jefferson had originally written the word, "sacred"; Jefferson's original version read, "We hold these truths to be sacred that all men are created equal and are endowed by their Creator........"

Comment: However, despite his use of the word, "sacred", Thomas Jefferson essentially coined (or at least popularized) the phrase, "Nature's God" and wrote his own demystified version of The New Testament called, "The Jefferson Bible".  So even though Thomas Jefferson used the word, "sacred" in the pre-edited text of "The Declaration of Independence", one should recognize that Thomas Jefferson's Deistic credentials were solid.

Comment: And perhaps the most Deistic of The Founding Fathers, was James Madison.  Although George Mason was largely responsible for ushering in "The Bill of Rights", I believe James Madison either directly authored or at least heavily influenced, "The Establishment Clause" within the 1st Amendment. If one looks at the "The Establishment Clause" very carefully, you will notice that it is almost an amendment......within an amendment.  In other words, "The Establishment Clause" is the opening or the introduction to the 1st Amendment, essentially standing in front of the Freedom of Speech and Press.

Comment: For Madison, the institutional distancing of religion and the state, as well as the maintenance of personal religious expression, was absolutely paramount and indispensable in helping to define the cultural and intellectual character of the U.S. Republic-(and nearly 230 years later.........The Establishment Clause has remained unchanged).

Comment: So as one can see, some of the most well known members of The Founding Fathers Generation were not Theists, nor were they practicing Christians.  They were Deists, essentially, men of The Enlightenment period who were probably influenced by Voltaire, as well as with the Pre-Enlightenment thinker, John Locke.

Comment: A historical side note.  The United States, as a Constitutionally based Republic, has never fought a war in the name or on behalf of.......religion.  This ultimately dates back to our founding, more specifically, to the establishment of The Establishment Clause and the time-honored commitment that every Government since President George Washington, the First Congress, as well as the First members of the U.S. Supreme Court have "preserved and protected".